# Php Contact form don't get the variables needed

Tags: php, flash, fla

I'm trying to generate the contact.php for a website, but it's not filling in the fields.
Right now I have this:

```
<?php
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$name = $_POST['nametxt'] ;
$message = $_POST['messagetxt'] ;
$subject = $_POST['subjecttxt'] ;
$from = $_POST['emailtxt'] ;
mail($to,$name,$message,$from,$subject);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

But I just recieve an empty e-mail. 
The original .fla is this [Here](http://www.2shared.com/file/uCa6HPgy/contact2.html).

This is from the form_4.as

```
package contact_fla
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.text.*;

dynamic public class form_4 extends MovieClip
{
    public var messagetxt:TextField;
    public var send_btn:MovieClip;
    public var nametxt:TextField;
    public var emailtxt:TextField;
    public var errortxt:TextField;
    public var reset_btn:MovieClip;
    public var subjecttxt:TextField;

    public function form_4()
    {
        return;
    }// end function

}
}
```

This is from Contactview.as

```
package pages.views
{
import com.gaiaframework.templates.*;
import com.shuhanarts.as3.*;
import com.shuhanarts.as3.ui.forms.*;
import com.shuhanarts.as3.utils.*;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.text.*;
import pages.utils.*;
import pages.views.components.*;

public class ContactView extends AbstractView
{
    protected var xml:XML;
    private var onOutColor:Number = 16777215;
    private var onOverColor:Number = 16776960;

    public function ContactView(param1:MovieClip, param2:Object, param3:AbstractPage =    null)
    {
        onOverColor = 16776960;
        onOutColor = 16777215;
        super(param1, param2, param3);
        onOverColor = Number(ConfigUtils.parseNavigate().setting.onOverColor);
        onOutColor = Number(ConfigUtils.parseNavigate().setting.onOutColor);
        TweenerButton.init();
        ColorUtil.setRGB(param1.form.form.reset_btn.icon, onOutColor);
        TweenerButton.run(param1.form.form.reset_btn.icon, "color", onOutColor, onOverColor);
        ColorUtil.setRGB(param1.form.form.send_btn.icon, onOutColor);
        TweenerButton.run(param1.form.form.send_btn.icon, "color", onOutColor, onOverColor);
        return;
    }// end function

    public function onLoadSourceInit(param1:XML) : void
    {
        this.xml = param1;
        _initUI();
        ON_LOAD_XML_COMPLETE.dispatch();
        return;
    }// end function

    protected function parseForm() : Object
    {
        var _loc_1:Object = null;
        var _loc_2:Object = null;
        var _loc_3:Object = null;
        _loc_1 = {};
        _loc_2 = {};
        _loc_3 = {};
        _loc_2.name = xml.form.name.@text;
        _loc_2.email = xml.form.email.@text;
        _loc_2.message = xml.form.message.@text;
        _loc_2.subject = xml.form.subject.@text;
        _loc_3.normalBorder = Number(xml.form.border.@normal);
        _loc_3.selectBorder = Number(xml.form.border.@focus);
        _loc_3.normalBackground = Number(xml.form.background.@normal);
        _loc_3.selectBackground = Number(xml.form.background.@focus);
        _loc_3.normalColor = Number(xml.form.text.@normal);
        _loc_3.selectColor = Number(xml.form.text.@focus);
        _loc_1.textObj = _loc_2;
        _loc_1.colorObj = _loc_3;
        _loc_1.active = xml.form.@active == "true" ? (true) : (false);
        return _loc_1;
    }// end function

    override public function initUI() : void
    {
        load();
        return;
    }// end function

    protected function _initUI() : void
    {
        var _loc_1:TextField = null;
        _loc_1 = container.txt;
        _loc_1.htmlText = xml.text.text();
        _loc_1.mouseWheelEnabled = false;
        _initPHPForm();
        return;
    }// end function

    public function load() : void
    {
        var _loc_1:String = null;
        var _loc_2:XMLLoader = null;
        _loc_1 = data.source;
        _loc_2 = new XMLLoader();
        _loc_2.ONLOADINIT_EVENT.add(onLoadSourceInit);
        _loc_2.load(_loc_1);
        return;
    }// end function

    protected function _initPHPForm() : void
    {
        var _loc_1:MovieClip = null;
        var _loc_2:Object = null;
        var _loc_3:PHPContactForm = null;
        _loc_1 = container.form;
        _loc_2 = parseForm();
        _loc_3 = new PHPContactForm(_loc_1, "contact.php", !_loc_2.active, _loc_2.textObj, _loc_2.colorObj);
        return;
    }// end function

}
}
```

May be from here :

```
package com.shuhanarts.as3.ui.forms
{
import com.shuhanarts.as3.*;
import com.shuhanarts.as3.ui.*;
import com.shuhanarts.as3.utils.*;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.text.*;

public class PHPContactForm extends Component
{
    private var _send_btn:Object;
    private var _file_url:String;
    private var _name_txt:SmartInputText;
    private var _subject_txt:SmartInputText;
    private var _target:MovieClip;
    private var _form_mc:MovieClip;
    private var _error_txt:TextField;
    private var _isPreview:Boolean;
    private var _messBox_mc:MovieClip;
    private var _textObj:Object;
    private var _email_txt:SmartInputText;
    private var _reset_btn:Object;
    private var _colorObj:Object;
    private var _mesBoxClode_btn:Object;
    private var _message_txt:SmartInputText;

    public function PHPContactForm(param1:MovieClip, param2:String =  "http://localhost/contact.php", param3:Boolean = false, param4:Object = null, param5:Object  = null)
    {
        this._target = param1;
        _form_mc = this._target.form;
        _messBox_mc = this._target.mesbox;
        _file_url = param2;
        _isPreview = param3;
        _textObj = param4;
        _colorObj = param5;
        init();
        return;
    }// end function

    private function setTextView() : void
    {
        if (!_textObj)
        {
            _email_txt = new SmartInputText(_form_mc.emailtxt, "Your Email");
            _name_txt = new SmartInputText(_form_mc.nametxt, "Your Name");
            _message_txt = new SmartInputText(_form_mc.messagetxt, "Your Message");
            _subject_txt = new SmartInputText(_form_mc.subjecttxt, "Your Subject");
        }
        else
        {
            _email_txt = new SmartInputText(_form_mc.emailtxt, _textObj.email);
            _name_txt = new SmartInputText(_form_mc.nametxt, _textObj.name);
            _message_txt = new SmartInputText(_form_mc.messagetxt, _textObj.message);
            _subject_txt = new SmartInputText(_form_mc.subjecttxt, _textObj.subject);
        }
        return;
    }// end function

    private function init() : void
    {
        setTextView();
        setColorView();
        _reset_btn = _form_mc.reset_btn;
        _send_btn = _form_mc.send_btn;
        _mesBoxClode_btn = _messBox_mc.close_btn;
        _error_txt = _form_mc.errortxt;
        _reset_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reset);
        _send_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, send);
        _mesBoxClode_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clodeMessageBox);
        return;
    }// end function

    private function setColorView() : void
    {
        if (!_colorObj)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            _name_txt.normalBorder = _colorObj.normalBorder;
            _name_txt.selectBorder = _colorObj.selectBorder;
            _name_txt.normalBackground = _colorObj.normalBackground;
            _name_txt.selectBackground = _colorObj.selectBackground;
            _name_txt.normalColor = _colorObj.normalColor;
            _name_txt.selectColor = _colorObj.selectColor;
            _name_txt.getTarget().textColor = _colorObj.normalColor;
            _email_txt.normalBorder = _colorObj.normalBorder;
            _email_txt.selectBorder = _colorObj.selectBorder;
            _email_txt.normalBackground = _colorObj.normalBackground;
            _email_txt.selectBackground = _colorObj.selectBackground;
            _email_txt.normalColor = _colorObj.normalColor;
            _email_txt.selectColor = _colorObj.selectColor;
            _email_txt.getTarget().textColor = _colorObj.normalColor;
            _subject_txt.normalBorder = _colorObj.normalBorder;
            _subject_txt.selectBorder = _colorObj.selectBorder;
            _subject_txt.normalBackground = _colorObj.normalBackground;
            _subject_txt.selectBackground = _colorObj.selectBackground;
            _subject_txt.normalColor = _colorObj.normalColor;
            _subject_txt.selectColor = _colorObj.selectColor;
            _subject_txt.getTarget().textColor = _colorObj.normalColor;
            _message_txt.normalBorder = _colorObj.normalBorder;
            _message_txt.selectBorder = _colorObj.selectBorder;
            _message_txt.normalBackground = _colorObj.normalBackground;
            _message_txt.selectBackground = _colorObj.selectBackground;
            _message_txt.normalColor = _colorObj.normalColor;
            _message_txt.selectColor = _colorObj.selectColor;
            _message_txt.getTarget().textColor = _colorObj.normalColor;
            _name_txt.update();
            _email_txt.update();
            _message_txt.update();
            _subject_txt.update();
        }
        return;
    }// end function

    private function send(event:MouseEvent = null) : void
    {
        var _loc_2:Boolean = false;
        var _loc_3:Boolean = false;
        var _loc_4:Boolean = false;
        var _loc_5:Boolean = false;
        _loc_2 = _name_txt.getText() != "" && _name_txt.isDefaultString();
        _loc_3 = _message_txt.getText() != "" && _message_txt.isDefaultString();
        _loc_4 = _subject_txt.getText() != "" && _subject_txt.isDefaultString();
        _loc_5 = StringUtil.isValidEmail(_email_txt.getText());
        if (_loc_2 == true)
        {
            _error_txt.text = "** Username Required **";
            _target.stage.focus = _name_txt.getTarget();
            return;
        }
        if (_loc_5 == false)
        {
            _error_txt.text = "** Missing field/Invalid email **";
            _target.stage.focus = _email_txt.getTarget();
            return;
        }
        if (_loc_4 == true)
        {
            _error_txt.text = "** Subject Required **";
            _target.stage.focus = _subject_txt.getTarget();
            return;
        }
        if (_loc_3 == true)
        {
            _error_txt.text = "** Message Required **";
            _target.stage.focus = _message_txt.getTarget();
            return;
        }
        $send();
        return;
    }// end function

    private function showMessageBox(param1:Number = 0) : void
    {
        _form_mc.mouseEnabled = false;
        _form_mc.mouseChildren = false;
        if (param1 == 0)
        {
            _messBox_mc.visible = true;
            _messBox_mc.gotoAndStop(2);
        }
        if (param1 == 1)
        {
            _messBox_mc.visible = true;
            _messBox_mc.gotoAndStop(3);
        }
        if (param1 == 2)
        {
            _messBox_mc.visible = true;
            _messBox_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
        }
        return;
    }// end function

    private function $send() : void
    {
        var loader:URLLoader;
        var req:URLRequest;
        var variables:URLVariables;
        var onSendComplete:Function;
        onSendComplete = function (event:Event) : void
        {
            var _loc_2:String = null;
            loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSendComplete);
            _loc_2 = URLVariables(event.target.data).retval;
            if (_loc_2 == "1")
            {
                _target.stage.focus = null;
                showMessageBox(2);
            }
            else
            {
                showMessageBox(0);
            }
            return;
        }// end function
        ;
        if (_isPreview == true)
        {
            _target.stage.focus = null;
            showMessageBox(2);
            return;
        }
        loader = new URLLoader();
        req = new URLRequest(_file_url);
        variables = new URLVariables();
        loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
        req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        variables.php_mail = _email_txt.getText();
        variables.php_subject = _subject_txt.getText();
        variables.php_message = _message_txt.getText();
        variables.php_name = _name_txt.getText();
        req.data = variables;
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSendComplete);
        showMessageBox(1);
        loader.load(req);
        return;
    }// end function

    private function reset(event:MouseEvent = null) : void
    {
        _email_txt.reset();
        _name_txt.reset();
        _message_txt.reset();
        _subject_txt.reset();
        _error_txt.text = "";
        return;
    }// end function

    private function clodeMessageBox(event:MouseEvent = null) : void
    {
        _messBox_mc.visible = false;
        _form_mc.mouseEnabled = true;
        _form_mc.mouseChildren = true;
        return;
    }// end function

}
}
```

Comment: Please show the Flash code that you're using to send the data

Comment: Where can I find it? (I don´t know about flash and php =( )

Comment: well, the code inside the Flash file that makes the request. It should be in Actionscript I think

Comment: Yep I know that, but since I don't know where to find it I uploaded the .fla, can you see it?

Comment: Does that help? (I put some code)

Comment: I don't speak much Actionscript but I think there is something missing here, I can't see the class `PHPContactForm` defined anywhere, that's where the action probably is...

Comment: `mail($to,$name,$message,$from,$subject);` is incorrect, i think.
Check the php documentation

Comment: incorrect where Shvelo? I already check the documentation and is not problem with that ( I think)

Comment: Pekka, I add another portion of code, where the PHPContactForm is defined

Comment: Indeed, the order of the arguments is not correct. If the E-Mail is completely empty, that can't be the whole reason

Comment: I think that maybe the correct variables names are in the last code, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed

The correct name of the variables are:

```
        ....    
        variables.php_mail = _email_txt.getText();
        variables.php_subject = _subject_txt.getText();
        variables.php_message = _message_txt.getText();
        variables.php_name = _name_txt.getText();
        ....
```

so de php code is:

```
<?php
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$name = $_REQUEST['php_name'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['php_message'] ;
$subject = $_REQUEST['php_subject'] ;
$from = $_REQUEST['php_mail'] ;
mail($to, $name, $message,$subject,$from);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```